# UIImageView ignores content mode form image data

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I am trying load an image from a data :

```
NSError *error ;
NSString  *imagePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:imageName ofType:@"png"];
NSData *encryptedData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];
NSData *decryptedData = [RNDecryptor decryptData:encryptedData
                                    withPassword:PASSWORD
                                           error:&error];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:decryptedData];

//adding image
UIImageView *movingImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:image];
[movingImageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
[self.scrollView addSubview:movingImageView];
```

now `movingImageView` ignores content mode !!! it will be fixed if I declare its frame ! but the problem is my datas are different images with different `width` size . Any solution  ?

**EDIT :**
Found a solution :

```
 movingImageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width/2, image.size.height/2);
```

Comment: `initWithImage:` sets the view frame to the size of the image, so all `contentMode` values will have the same effect. You need to set the frame separately for `contentMode` to change how the image is shown.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation:

> initWithImage: adjusts the frame of the receiver to match the size of the specified image. It also disables user interactions for the image view by default.`

Obviously the `contentMode` will have no effect if the `imageView` and `image` have the same size.

I guess what you need is to specify the `imageView`'s `width` (probably the same as scrollView?), and calculate the height according to the `image`'s dimension.

Answer (score 0):

use the following lines. it will fill the image to frame. if large image came it will show image with aspect ratio and some part may clips. try once.

```
    movingImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
movingImageView.clipsToBounds = YES;[self.scrollView addSubview:movingImageView];
```